# Specify an enum as the content and also have an attribute in a single type in xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to define the following in a single type in an xml schema?

```
<Foo bar="1">ENUM</Foo>
```

It has to be a `simpleType` because it's a `restriction` on what the string can be, but then it can't have an `attribute`.

```
<element name="Foo">
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="string">
            <!-- some enums... -->
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</element>
```

If I make it a `simpleType` with `extension` for the attribute then there is no way to specify the enumerations.

```
<element name="Foo">
    <simpleType>
        <extension base="string">
            <attribute name="bar" type="positiveInteger" />
        </extension>
    </simpleType>
</element>
```

I tried to do a `simpleContent` or `complexContent` but then you can't add in the attribute. In addition I think the base type has to be complex.

**Is there any way to do this in a single `element` element without adding an additional type?**

Below is a way to do it with an additional type.

```
<element name="Foo">
    <complexType>
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="this:FooEnum">
                <attribute name="bar" type="positiveInteger" />
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
</element>

<simpleType name="FooEnum">
    <restriction base="string">
        <!-- some enums... -->
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Comment: ََAFAIK, this is not possible in XSD 1.0.

Comment: @Win.ubuntu I've just posted an XSD1.0 answer using xs:anyType that allows you to do it without creating a global type. However, I really prefer the notation that the OP has explained in his question.

Comment: I was not even aware there were multiple "versions" of xsd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0 solution

In XSD 1.0 you can do something like that by restricting `xs:anyType`:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="value1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="value2"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Note that if you want you can move the `xs:enumeration` nodes as sibling of the `xs:attribute` node, but you cannot remove the `xs:simpleType` node:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>                        
                </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:enumeration value="value1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="value2"/>
                <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

### XSD 1.1 solution

Using XSD 1.1 you can use `mixed=true` and express the enumeration as an assertion of the complexType although this is not as expressive as a XSD enum. Basic example:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        <xs:assert test=". = ('value1', 'value2')"/> <!-- Value in enum -->            
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: That is *ugly* haha. It is the same number of lines though, believe it or not (of course it loses on indentation). Could you edit in an example of what you meant in the last paragraph? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @CaptainMan Sure, I've edited my answer explaining it, the result has the same number of lines. I've also added an XSD 1.1 solution, if you can are using Saxon or Xerces you should be able to use XSD 1.1 mode.

Comment: @sergioFC awesome, thank you for the in-depth answer. I would point out though that the second 1.0 solution *is* one line shorter because you don't need the `</xs:restriction>` tag.

Comment: @CaptainMan You're welcome. Yes 1 line shorter, it's something :)